# PHP Replacement for GET Method Link

Tags: php

I apologize as this question may be too broad.

I have a table on my site that displays all users in a database. For each row in the database I create a link in the table that allows the corresponding user to be removed. I do this using `http_build_query`. The `$qs` array contains the variables I am sending to the next script.

```
echo '<th><div class="right"><a onclick="return confirm(\'Are you sure you want to completely remove '.$name.' from your officer list?\')" href="./php/remove-officer.php?'.http_build_query($qs, null, '&amp;', PHP_QUERY_RFC3986).'">Remove</a></div></th>';
```

Once the link is clicked it runs the removal script. The script gets the correct row to remove using `GET`.

```
$name = $_GET['name'];
$code = $_GET['code'];
$branch = $_GET['branch'];
$email = $_GET['email'];
```

I have recently seen on here that a `GET` method really shouldnt be used to alter a `db`. My understanding is that this is for security reasons. 
The url never really gets displayed but if I go to my servers log you can obviously still see it

> ::1 - - [09/Aug/2019:13:16:42 -0500] "GET
>   /php/remove-user.php?user=bob%40builder.net&name=Robert%20Builder&branch=5&officer=n%2Fa&type=Limited&alert=0
>   HTTP/1.1" 302 -

At the end of the removal script, the user is immediately redirected back to the page displaying the users table.

So my questions are the following:

1.) Does this pose a risk for my db/site?

2.) What are some alternatives I could use to make this more secure? If possible I would still want to be able to use the `Remove` link.

I will include any requested additional info in Edits.

Comment: My suggestion is to put in your link to the backend only the ID of the user. Instead on backend you can write a Prepared Statement to avoid SQL injection. Another thing, if you have some concept of "levels" on your site, like normal and admin maybe you can avoid deleting an admin from your app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does this pose a risk for my db/site?

There's nothing that appears to be a *security* risk there … but GET requests are supposed to be **safe** and people have been known to run precaching extensions (which would store the data from the URLs in the cache before visiting them … deleting everything as they went).

> What are some alternatives I could use to make this more secure?

Using a form and a post request would do the job.

```
<form method="post" action="./php/remove-officer.php" onsubmit="your-js-here">
    <input type="hidden" name="user" value="bob">
    <!-- etc -->
    <button> Remove</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, I believe this can be my solution. I do have a question though. Lets say I need two pieces of data about the user to remove them. Something like `$user` and `$name`. Is there a way to make sure the `value` can contain both `$user` and `$name`? There are some entries in my database where two rows may have the same `$user` and two may have the same `$name` but none have both the same.

Comment: @FamousAv8er — See `<!-- etc -->`. Put as many hidden inputs as you like.